# How to find the centroid of a set of points

Tags: geometry

I am looking for simple way to find the the centroid of the following list  of points.

```
points = 
{{298, 87}, {299, 87}, {300, 87}, {301, 87}, {302, 87},{303, 87}, 
 {304, 87}, {305, 87}, {306, 87}, {297, 86}, {298, 86}, {307, 86},  
 {308, 86}, {296, 85}, {300, 85}, {301, 85}, {302, 85}, {303,  85},   
 {304, 85}, {305, 85}, {308, 85}, {309, 85}, {295, 84}, {298, 84}, 
 {299, 84}, {306, 84}, {307, 84}, {309, 84}, {310, 84}, {294, 83},                     
 {297, 83}, {298, 83}, {307, 83}, {308, 83}, {310, 83}, {294, 82}, 
 {296, 82}, {297, 82}, {308, 82}, {311, 82}, {293, 81}, {296, 81}, 
 {309, 81}, {311, 81}, {293, 80}, {295, 80}, {296, 80}, {309, 80}, 
 {312, 80}, {293, 79}, {295, 79}, {309, 79}, {312, 79}, {293, 78}, 
 {295, 78}, {309, 78}, {312, 78}, {293, 77}, {295, 77}, {309, 77},    
 {312, 77}, {293, 76}, {295, 76}, {296, 76},{309, 76}, {312, 76},   
 {293, 75}, {296, 75}, {309, 75}, {311, 75}, {294, 74}, {296, 74},    
 {297, 74}, {308, 74}, {311, 74}, {294, 73}, {295, 73}, {297, 73}, 
 {298, 73}, {307, 73}, {308, 73}, {310, 73}, {295, 72}, {298, 72},    
 {299, 72}, {306, 72}, {307, 72}, {309, 72}, {310, 72}, {296, 71}, 
 {300, 71}, {301, 71}, {302, 71}, {303, 71}, {304, 71}, {305,  71},   
 {308, 71}, {309, 71}, {297, 70}, {298, 70}, {307, 70}, {308, 70},  
 {298, 69}, {299, 69}, {300, 69}, {301, 69}, {304, 69}, {305, 69},     
 {306, 69}, {302,68}, {303, 68}}
```

The points are roughly arranged in a circle.

[image]

Comment: `Mean[points]`.

Comment: @Quantum_Oli Nice! Write it as an answer and I will +1

Comment: `RegionCentroid[Point[points]]` too

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue it raises is not really a  Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the mathematics involved..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Graphics[{Point /@ points, Red, Point@Mean@points}]
```

[image]

Comment: Mapping `Point` is unnecessary. `Graphics[{Point[points], Red, Point@Mean@points}]` is both shorter and faster.

Comment: Yeah I remembered that shortly after!